# Combine two querysets, common field with different values

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I search in a model "ConsultantProfile", the relevance is represented by a field called "rank" in "queryset1".

I Also search in related models and gather "ConsultantProfile" objects from that related models in "queryset2" and set rank manually "0.7" for them so i can union query sets.

When i want to combine and merge queryset1 and queryset2, common objects have different rank values. The problem is in final "queryset" the "rank" field's value is a value of rank from first queryset and i can't choose the highest value for "rank"

```
queryset1 = qs.filter(active=True).annotate(
    rank=SearchRank(
        vector,
        query,
        normalization=Value(2).bitor(Value(4)),
    )
)

ids: some "ConsultantProfile" objects ids

queryset2 = ConsultantProfile.objects.filter(id__in=ids, active=True).annotate(rank=Value(5, FloatField()))

queryset = queryset1 | queryset2
```

**Failed solution**
I tried to solve the problem by iterate over both query sets and union manually but no thing changed!

```
queryset = queryset1.none()

for obj in queryset1:
    qs2_object_qs = queryset2.filter(id=obj.id)

    # object presents in queryset2
    if qs2_object_qs.exists():

        # obj from queryset1 has better rank than queryset2 obj
        if obj.rank >= qs2_object_qs.first().rank:k)
            queryset |= queryset1.filter(id=obj.id)
            queryset2 = queryset2.exclude(id=obj.id)
        else:
            queryset |= qs2_object_qs

    # object does not present in queryset2
    else:
        queryset |= queryset1.filter(id=obj.id)

for obj in queryset2:
    qs_object_qs = queryset.filter(id=obj.id)

    # object presents in queryset
    if qs_object_qs.exists():
        # because compared mutual objects in previous loop and removed
        pass
    else:
        queryset |= queryset2.filter(id=obj.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use union() beside " | " operand.
in union method duplicate objects will not remove.But after order('-rank') distinct() will not work.

the thing i did is that i found common objects in " | " operand result and removed the object with lower rank from it's query set and then used union function.

```
temp_queryset = queryset1 | queryset2

for obj in temp_queryset:
    try:
        qs1_object = queryset1.get(id=obj.id)
        qs2_object = queryset2.get(id=obj.id)
        if qs1_object.rank > qs2_object.rank:
            queryset2 = queryset2.exclude(id=obj.id)
        else:
            queryset1 = queryset1.exclude(id=obj.id)
    except ConsultantProfile.DoesNotExist:
        pass

queryset = queryset1.union(queryset2)

queryset = queryset.order_by('-rank')
```